# Spring Boot JPA Hibernate Multiple Datasouce Properties Settings

Tags: spring, spring-boot

```
#############################
###mysql datasource
############################
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://111.222.333.444:3306/source1
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name= com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

#############################
###oracle datasource
############################
spring.datasource.oracle.url =jdbc:oracle:thin:test:@//localhost:1521/source2
spring.datasource.oracle.username =test
spring.datasource.oracle.password =test
spring.datasource.oracle.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver

###########################
###Spring JPA
##########################
#spring.jpa.database = mysql
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

I have Spring JPA section for mysql.

How to add another **Spring JPA section** for my oracle datasource?

How to use both **Oracle and Mysql with JPA**?

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the documentation you can not used the Spring boot auto-configuration, you need to configure two entity managers and two transaction managers.

[How to use two entity managers](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-use-two-entity-managers)

Just make sure every entity manager scan their entities. [Stephane Nicoll](https://stackoverflow.com/users/613628/stephane-nicoll) has a nice example for this in github:

[Demo multi entity managers](https://github.com/snicoll-demos/demo-multi-entity-managers)